# C# Web-Api - processing inbound requests 'in order that they are recieved'

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I've written a web-api project to act as a bridge/gateway between two sub-systems.

I need to ensure that inbound requests are processed 'in the order that they are received'.  I'm not overaly familiar with how web-api works and the concern I have is this:

1. An inbound request comes in, an operation is kicked off and lasts 30 seconds.
2. Within 5 seconds of the first request being processed, and second request is received and is immediately also processed.

The reason for the concern is that a user may submit an update to a record which will propagate to the other sub-system.  However that user may for whatever reason submit a second request.  I need to ensure that the first request is completed first, before the subsequent request is actioned.  So when hundres of requests are flooding in, it's just a case of processing on a first come, first served basis.

Does anyone know if web-api sort of works like this already, or what I'd need to do in order to get this behaviour?

Comment: pretty sure there is no such mechanism out of the box in the Web API, since you'd need some kind of key to lock the other requests by. Still, to solve your problem you'll need some kind of semaphore mechanism. But you should also think about possible timeouts in this case..

Comment: Depending on what you want to send back to the user, you could queue the requests and send back a 'queued' response.  Not specific to Web-API but would cover your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this this by using global static flag.
Declare one variable like this

```
static bool bInProcess = false;
```

Now, when you receive request set this variable to true and do your process. Once you done with your process set this variable to false; During your process if another request come then check this variable if its true then put current thread in sleep mode for 1 sec and check until its true. OR you can return error that another process is running.

```
//Sample for loop to Queue 2nd request 
while (bInProcess )
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

You have to be very careful in this code. In "WebApiConfig" class add the messagehandler class and write this code in that class. Use this method "config.MessageHandlers.Add". I did it long time ago, so I know it works.

Comment: How is this 1. Thread-Safe? 2.  Sleeping is going to block your thread -Boo. 3. Why not just use a concurrency token?\